# Creating a ROS optional Library

Tags: boost, cmake, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to write a library (in this case a boost based cross platform serial C++ library) that when in a ROS environment is built with rosbuild and easily depended upon by other ROS packages, but in the event that ROS is not present the package will build using cmake and make only.  The only thing I am looking for is a best practice for checking for ROS environment and tips for righting a graceful cmake file to accommodate this type of setup.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9401/creating-a-ros-optional-library/) by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17335 on 2011-03-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the new cmake/catkin based system coming out in fuerte you can use cmake's find_package and if package_FOUND variables to do this logic.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the best way would be to make the library standalone and create an additional ros interface for it like mylib and mylib_ros.

I am not sure, but for the library's cmake file it might even be OK to use a plain (without ros_...) commands even in a ros package as you don't have an ros dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1